# AngularJS: mutual dependencies in components

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components

I have two components that have a lot of cross-references. I decided to make them depend on each other:

`taskList` component:

```
angular.module("todo-feature")
    .component("taskList", {
        templateUrl: "feature/todo-feature/todo_table.html",
        controller: "Todo",
        require: {
            "parent": "paging"
        }
    });
```

`paging` component

```
angular.module("paging-module")
    .component('paging', {
        templateUrl: "feature/todo-feature/paging/paging.html",
        controller: "PagingController",
        require: {
            "parent": "taskList"
        }
    });
```

`index.html`:

```
<paging></paging>
<task-list></task-list>
```

It doesn't work. I receive two errors:

```
 Controller 'paging', required by directive 'taskList', can't be found!
 Controller 'taskList', required by directive 'paging', can't be found!
```

How can I fix it? Is it good architecture at all? What would you recommend?

Comment: Neither of two components doesn't have another one as a parent. They are siblings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not advisable from design perspective to create such a tightly dependent components. Instead you can create common service and share the data between them or you can create a parent component on top of paging and tasklist component to manage this both components. Check which is more suitable in your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the require syntax should be something like `parentCtrl: "^taskList"`. this will look for the required controller from its element to its parents. read more about this in the api doc [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).

Implementing require in both component to refer each other is not advaisable and probably it wont work.

I would recommend that you can have a common service  or have parent-child components and implement one-way bindings